# How to prevent one table from obeying CSS rule

Tags: css

I already have the following CSS in my stylesheet which adds a counter to each row for all tables in the app:

```
tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

tbody tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

I now have one table that I don't want to add the counter to, i.e., disobey the CSS rule, out of the scores of tables that the site generates. Would I need to put a unique class name for those three table elements for those tables I want to obey those rules, and then change the CSS accordingly? Ugh. Just thought there may be a way of saying, 'don't follow the css on this table' for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a class to the tables that should ignore the counter styles (e.g., `no-counter`). Then alter your styles like so:

```
table:not(.no-counter) tbody {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table:not(.no-counter) tbody tr {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table:not(.no-counter) tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

So tables that should **not** have counters would look like this:

```
<table class="no-counter">
   ...
</table>
```

More info about `:not` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to apply styles additively. That is, add a class to *all* your tables, then change the CSS:

```
.mytable tbody {}
.mytable tbody > tr {}
```

and so on. You will almost always encounter `<table>`s where you do not want the specific, site-wide styles, and then it's as trivial as leaving the `mytable` class from the table element.

If you can't do that, another option is the `:not()` selector: Exclude all tables with a class `plain`:

```
table:not(.plain) tbody {}
```